# IR2110 - open-collector output problem

Tags: inverter, pullup, open-collector

I'm trying to design an inverter and I'm using two IR2110 as gate drivers, but my MCU board PWM outputs are open collector. I've added a pull-up and transistor to feed the IR2110 with 5 V pulses but it's not working.

Here is the full bridge and gate drive I'm using:

[image]

Here is the pull-up and transistor schematic I'm using between the IR2110 PWM input and MCU open collector output (ULN2003A):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZco0R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is not working *exactly*? Did you measure HIN and LIN on an oscilloscoop? Moreover, do measure VB as well. I think your problem lies there: remove C1 and C5 and check whether it improves (EDIT: I removed "whether it works" since when works or does help a bit, you probably still need to put the correct (values of the) caps there.)

Comment: @Huisman thanks for your answer, but the problem is: At the input of  R2 I can detect a pulse but at the output of R2, there is no signal (2. schematic R2) so the bc337 is not working here but I don't know why

Comment: You doublechecked the pinning of the BC337? What voltages do you measure at the input of R2? And what voltages at the base of BC337?

Comment: @Huisman at the input of R2, There is a square pulse with 3V , but at the base I have only noise. Pins are connected true I check it many times :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved; I forgot to add a pull-down resistor to the base of the transistor.