# Invert signal and drop voltage from 5V to 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller

I have inverted 5V signal from a sensor device (SBUS, inverted UART) and need to able to feed it UART port of Raspberry Pi Pico:

1. invert it
2. drop voltage of the inverted signal from 5V to 3.3V

Assuming I have two voltage sources, 3.3V and 5V. One voltage source powers Pico board at 3.3V, another independently powers my sensor at 5V.

To invert signal I thought to use 74HC04 logic gate, but I'm not sure if I could use the same chip to also drop the voltage? If I connect Vdd to 3.3V from Pico?

What is the most practical way to achieve my goal?

Comment: second schematic diagram ... use 3.3 V at V2 ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432154/ir2110-open-collector-output-problem

Comment: Why not to use simple resistor divider to reduce from 5v to 3v3?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický how?

Comment: Important question: do you need bidirectional or unidirectional communication?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this simple approach possible for Sensor Tx to Pico Rx?
(iverter is supplied with 5v Vcc)

[image]

Pico Tx to sensor Rx you can do with Op-Amp as comparator (Op-Amp 5v Vcc). (No need for additional inverting since comparator is conected as inverter)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdqmmc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd use dual-voltage inverting level translator, like [NLSV1T240](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nlsv1t240-d.pdf). However it is hard to find a chip with low channel count and 5V support.

So, what you can do, is find an **inverting buffer** that can tolerate input voltage higher than VCC. Luckily, there are plenty of these, for example [SN74LVC1G240](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g240.pdf). Note in description: "Inputs Accept Voltages to 5.5V; *Provides Down Translation to VCC*". When you search for a part, make sure its input voltage limit is not based on VCC (like "Vcc + 0.5V"), and you should be OK.

You can also find **inverting gate** with inputs tolerating voltage higher than VCC. There are plenty of these too, for example [SN74LVC1G04](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf). From description in datasheet: "Inputs Accept Voltages up to 5.5 V *Allowing Down Translation to VCC*".

All of the above provide a simple 1-component solution.

Yet another option is to use basic non-inverting level shifter and **program RPi UART RX pin** for inverted logic. Here is a [discussion](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=306053) at RPi forums on how to do this. Of course, you can do this for TX pin as well, if you need bidirectional communication. For a shifter you can use either a chip, like [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1t45.pdf) or a premade [module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with working with ESP01 EP8266 and GSM SIM800L modules which both require a **3.3V** logic from the Arduino TX to the modules' RX pin.  Yes the voltage divider is the solution and I agree its the best solution. But lately I've been thinking of using a ** NPN Transistor** to have the TX pin into the base while collector connected to a 3.3V which gives the **3.3V to the RX.** (Note I've not tested the circuit but I have confidence it will work).
I hope my two cents can assist you in your Raspberry Pico project and All the best.